# Animate Bootstrap carousel caption & button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In carousel want to animate caption and button with some delay below is the code i copied from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6xq12bh/4/)
 but in my jsfiddle it is animation is not working and infact slides is not showing as well.

HTML

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 class="toggleHeading">Caption Text</h3>
      <p class="toggleCaption">This is some text<p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 class="toggleHeading">Caption Text 2</h3>
       <p class="toggleCaption">This is some text<p>
  </div>
  </div>
     <div class="item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 class="toggleHeading">Caption Text 3</h3>
       <p class="toggleCaption">This is some text<p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

 <!-- Controls -->
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

JS

```
  var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
   var slideInterval = 5000;

function toggleH(){
    $('.toggleHeading').hide()
    var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleHeading').addClass('animated fadeInRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
        function (){
        $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInRight')});
caption.slideToggle();
}

function toggleC(){
    $('.toggleCaption').hide()
    var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleCaption').addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
        function (){
        $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp')
});
caption.slideToggle();
}
  carouselContainer.carousel({
  interval: slideInterval, cycle: true, pause: "hover"})
 .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
 .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
```

CSS

```
 .toggleHeading {
animation-delay: 0.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
   -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: none !important;
}

 .toggleCaption {
animation-delay: 1.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
   -o-animation-delay: 1.5s;
   -moz-transition: none !important;
 }
```

[Please check this fiddle with my code](http://jsfiddle.net/yomozon/cmdvrhwz/1/)
 and this is not working accordingly.

Comment: It looks like in your jsFiddle you've not included the external resources. Here's a forked version which includes them: http://jsfiddle.net/cgmeL350/

Comment: i agree i forgot to add external resources but shop now button is not animating still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated With Delay**

Tweaked the HTML and moved the header and button into their own divs so that the CSS applied the delay animations appropriately.

HTML:

```
 <!-- Header Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="toggleCaption">
                     <h3>Caption Text</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="toggleButton">
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button">Shop Now</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="toggleCaption">
                     <h3>Caption Text</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="toggleButton">
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button">Shop Now</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="toggleCaption">
                     <h3>Caption Text</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="toggleButton">
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button">Shop Now</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

    </div>
    <!-- Carousel -->
```

CSS:

```
.toggleCaption {
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
}
.toggleButton {
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
    var slideInterval = 5000;

    function toggleH() {
        $('.toggleCaption').hide()
        var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleCaption').addClass('animated fadeInRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',

        function () {
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInRight')
        });
        caption.slideToggle();
    }

    function toggleC() {
        $('.toggleButton').hide()
        var button = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleButton').addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',

        function () {
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp')
        });
        button.slideToggle();
    }
    carouselContainer.carousel({
        interval: slideInterval,
        cycle: true,
        pause: "hover"
    })
        .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
        .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
});
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lwyc6rb/1/

Comment: But i want caption and button with some delay

Comment: @user1120133 Sorry, could you be more specific? Delay on which elements?

Comment: first caption should animate first and then after a bit of delay then shop now button should animate in carousel

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have Jquery library set in your JSfiddle. Find updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cmdvrhwz/2/

```
var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 5000;

    function toggleH(){
        $('.toggleHeading').hide()
        var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleHeading').addClass('animated fadeInRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
            function (){
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInRight')});
    caption.slideToggle();
    }

    function toggleC(){
        $('.toggleCaption').hide()
        var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleCaption').addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
            function (){
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp')
    });
    caption.slideToggle();
    }
carouselContainer.carousel({
interval: slideInterval, cycle: true, pause: "hover"})
.on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
.on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
```

Comment: but still shop now button is not animating at all

Comment: Because you didnt add the class for the animation to your text, here's the shop now button animating http://jsfiddle.net/cmdvrhwz/6/

Comment: Right now both are animating together without any delay. I want some delay between caption and button

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some externals files:

- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
- https://rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css

Also you have to select jquery.

here is your code adding the files: http://jsfiddle.net/cmdvrhwz/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
    var slideInterval = 5000;
        function toggleH(){
            $('.toggleCaption').hide()
            var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleCaption').addClass('animated fadeInRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
                function (){
                $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInRight')});
        caption.slideToggle();
        }

        function toggleC(){
            $('.toggleButton').hide()
            var button = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleButton').addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
                function (){
                $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp')
        });
        button.slideToggle();
        }
    carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval, cycle: true, pause: "hover"})
    .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
    .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
});
```

Hope it's hepls

Answer (score 0):

JS in the above answers have to tweak a bit to get it working in Bootstrap 4.x:

The last line has to change to:

```
carouselContainer.carousel({
  interval: slideInterval, cycle: true, pause: "hover"
})
.on('slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
.on('slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
```

otherwise, the animation will be triggered two times.